# undefined: revel.LoadConfig on revel app start

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo, revel

I was following [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@kyawmyintthein/revel-mgo-restful-generator-for-revel-web-framework-mongodb-86209de3977e#.jwddppv6h) on using Go + Revel + MongoDB. But as I starting the application, I got this error:

```
The Go code api-go/app/init.go does not compile: undefined: revel.LoadConfig
```

along with other errors as I look in the terminal.

```
ERROR 2016/10/18 17:15:06 build.go:108: # api-go/app
api-go/app/init.go:41: undefined: revel.LoadConfig
api-go/app/init.go:43: undefined: log in log.Fatalf
api-go/app/init.go:45: undefined: mongodb in mongodb.MaxPool
api-go/app/init.go:45: cannot assign to mongodb.MaxPool
api-go/app/init.go:46: undefined: mongodb in mongodb.PATH
api-go/app/init.go:46: cannot assign to mongodb.PATH
api-go/app/init.go:47: undefined: mongodb in mongodb.DBNAME
api-go/app/init.go:47: cannot assign to mongodb.DBNAME
api-go/app/init.go:48: undefined: mongodb in mongodb.CheckAndInitServiceConnection
```

I used Mac Sierra. What's wrong with my application?

[image: error on browser]

Comment: Do you have all your import properly made? For example do you have "log" in your imports ?

Comment: I'm new to Go development. In which file do you mean? In controllers, models?

Comment: As I see your errors I think you should add in your file "init.go" this code `import ( "log" "github.com/revel/revel" “myapp/app/models/mongodb” ) ` This just under the first line of your init.go whitch contain "package"

Comment: I add your code. This time, all the errors disappear except `api-go/app/init.go:45: undefined: revel.LoadConfig`

Answer (score 1):

Comment this lines:

```
//Config, err := revel.LoadConfig("app.conf")
//if err != nil || Config == nil {
//        log.Fatalf("%+v",err)
//}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I see your errors I think you should add in your file "init.go" this code

```
     import ( 
        "log"
        "github.com/revel/revel" 
        “myapp/app/models/mongodb”
      )
```

This just under the first line of your init.go whitch contain "package"

Next in your code you have to replace:

```
   revel.LoadConfig("app.conf")
```

by

```
   revel.config.LoadContext("app.conf",ConfPaths)
```

where confPaths is the string path to your conf file. In your case it can be:

```
    ConfPaths := "conf/"
```

or

```
    ConfPaths := ""
```

Comment: now the error changes to `cannot refer to unexported name revel.config`

Comment: and `revel.LoadConfig("app.conf")`  said what ?

Comment: or try    `revel.Config.LoadContext("app.conf",ConfPaths)` The change is that "Config" begin with an uppercase, which mean you can access it from another packages when you import it

Answer (score 0):

That works for me. Imports:

```
import (
    "github.com/melkor217/myapp/app/models/mongodb"
    "github.com/revel/config"
    "github.com/revel/revel"
    "log"
)
```

Load config:

```
Config, err := config.LoadContext("app.conf", revel.ConfPaths)
```